# Add subdirectory for locale based URL existing ASP.NET website, resolve relative paths correctly

Tags: asp.net, seo, iis-7.5, multilingual, url-rewrite-module

Existing ASP.NET (MVC and webforms hybrid) website displays translated content. The language is based on a cookie that stores the user's preference. There is no change in the URL when the user changes the setting. The content is reloaded in the preferred language. 
For SEO, the locale should be included in the URL ( support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182192?hl=en).

I've tried the following:
**1) Use URL Rewrite Module:** (http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/setting-http-request-headers-and-iis-server-variables)
*Issues:* 
- All hyperlinks and redirects still point to the old URL without the locale.
- Complex outbound rules required based on the folder structure and usage (mixture of absolute paths and relative paths e.g. ../, ~/, /).
- Also need to disable static compression as per documentation
- Performance considerations due to large size of Html.
- Postback results in runtime exceptions due to issue in the relative path rewrite.
- Paths defined in script files (ajax loading etc) are a huge challenge
- Base tag does not work as expected, because the Rewrite Module seems to append ../ (http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewriting-for-aspnet-web-forms#Using_tilda)

**2) IIS 7.5 Virtual Directory:**
 Create Virtual Directory for each language and point it to the root. i.e. www.example.com is the root and www.example.com/fr-ca/ is a virtual directory mapped back to the root 
*Issues:* 
- Runtime exception in config file saying that the virtual directory needs to be converted to application
-  Converting it to application gives 500.19 error due to duplicate entries in the web config (since the virtual directory is pointing back to the root)
- I tried moving the root to another subdirectory (i.e. have a physical directory for each language) to avoid web config conflicts, but that is resulting in some sort of "kernel" error. Also, this would mean changing the physical structure of the application, and also address routing issues

**3) Using sub-domains:**
I have also considered using sub-domains and hosting the application independently for each language, but this has a lot of drawbacks, including having to address scalability,  single sign on, cookies, domain specific stuff like analytics etc.

So what is the least painful way to include a language sub-directory in the URL, and make all links relative to that sub-directory?

**Note:** The site contains a mixture of absolute paths and relative paths e.g. (../, ~/, /) sometimes used in conjunction with ResolveClientUrl, ResolveUrl

Answer (score 0):

In the end, we went with option 2, with the below steps:

1. Create a new folder, deploy a copy of the application to the new folder. The new folder should be in a different directory from the root application.
2. Create a new **virtual application*** (not virtual directory) under the root application; 1 for each new language, pointing to the new folder. (If the need arises in the future, any of the virtual applications can point a different folder customized for that specific language)
3. In the new folder, remove the modules and handlers sections in the system.webServer section of the web.config file (they will be inherited from the parent web.config)
4. If you are using SQL session state, you will need to specify a custom Application Name in the web.config, and modify TempGetAppID stored procedure so that the Application Name is the same across all the virtual applications. See the following (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/toddca/archive/2007/01/25/sharing-asp-net-session-state-across-applications.aspx)
5. Hopefully, all the links are resolved on the server side using Url.Content (MVC) or ResolveUrl (webforms). If not, they need to be fixed. Any paths specified in javascript would not automatically resolve to the virtual application either (they would still be resolved to root application)
6. Test the heck out of it. Each and every link. (A tool like ScreamingFrog may help to make sure that no 404s are returned, methinks. But it wouldn't solve HTTP POST)
7. Note that depending on custom error handling, and any existing URL rewrite rules, the steps maybe different.

**Summary:** option 1 (URL Rewrite) is totally impractical. Option 2 (sub-directory) is the most practical solution, however it is not quite as straightforward as it should've been.